# Mongoose: Get new version of a document after an update

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, feathersjs, mongodb-replica-set

We have a MongoDB replica and read to the scondaries, in the backend we use feathersjs with feathers-mongoose and the Document has a SubDocument. After doing a patch we get back the old subdocument. We already set `new: true` and also tried `returnNewDocument: true`

```
const params = {
    mongoose: {
        new: true
    }
}
```

A look in the documentation of feathers-mongoose told me that mongoose in params should be given as options to mongoose: https://github.com/feathersjs-ecosystem/feathers-mongoose#paramsmongoose

But the SubDocument has still the old id. Is there something spezial todo for SubDocuments?
I am also confused about the documentation of mongoose and mongodb because mongoDB seam only to know `returnNewDocument` and mongoose only `new`?

MongoDB: https://docs.mongodb.com/v4.2/reference/method/db.collection.findOneAndUpdate/

Mongoose: https://mongoosejs.com/docs/migration.html#findandmodify-new

The Schema looks like:

```
const timeSchema = new Schema({
    weekday: {
        type: Number,
        min: 0,
        max: 6,
        required: true,
    },
    startTime: { type: Number },
    duration: { type: Number },
    eventId: { type: String },
    room: { type: String },
});

const courseSchema = getUserGroupSchema({
    description: { type: String },
    startDate: { type: Date },
    untilDate: { type: Date },
    shareToken: {
        type: String,
        unique: true,
        sparse: true,
    },

    // here is the reference
    times: [timeSchema],

    // optional information if this course is a copy from other
    isCopyFrom: { type: Schema.Types.ObjectId, default: null },
    features: [{ type: String, enum: Object.values(COURSE_FEATURES) }],
    ...externalSourceSchema,
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Simple.

You can just use the `.save()` function to get the updated document.

Example :

```
...

let course = await CourseSchema.findById(id); //let's say
if(!course){
   throw new Error(...);
}

course.times.weekday = 5;
course.times.startTime = 9;
let updated = course.save();

console.log(updated); // Updated document will be printed.

...
```

You can also use the `findOneAndUpdate` method.

Comment: Hi thank you for your reply, but two point. 1. It is not my own code and there is currently used feathers-monogoose, so I could not directly call the model or schema. I also thought about to go around this and just connect drictly to the schme, but for the first step I wanted to keep the workflow of this service. 2. findOneAndUpdate will return a old object if not setting new or returnNewDocument, like written in the documentation. I think feathers-mongoose do a findOneAndUpdate in the background. But how to pass the options to get the new object.